# In Laravel Signed URLs throwing 403 error with additional parameters using Spatie/laravel-url-signer package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

I just used signed url package (https://github.com/spatie/laravel-url-signer) to protect direct access of my urls and it is working fine with no additional parameters but a url with *additional parameters* is generating **403 error**. I'm using **Laravel 5.4** and my code is as follows:

**This is my Route**

```
Route::get('/get-user', ['middleware' => 'signedurl', 'uses' => 'HomeController@getUser']);
```

**This is my function**

```
public function getUser(Request $request)
{
    print_r($request->all());
}
```

**This is my url generated by this package**

```
"http://localhost/MYPROJECT/get-user?expires=1557553652&signature=0bd90275ad12f422dc13b167cb75a829&zip=90038&isTomorrow=1&timeslot=d86c1db3-96ae-497d-bc96-2426adg4g43"
```

If I run above generated url in browser, it will throw **403 error** but if I'll run this url only with expires and signature, it will work fine. I want signed url working with additional parameters with this package.
Please help me out! Thanks in advance.. :-)

Comment: dump signedurl middleware

Comment: dumping signedurl middleware means what exactly I have to do?

Comment: My guess they they mean ditch it, don't use it. It's not maintained and has been a part of Laravel since 5.6.12 https://laravel-news.com/signed-routes